# The function $f(x)$ passes through the point $(-1,6)$ and $f'(x)=3x^2+2x+1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, math-software

a) find $f(x)$

I found that to be $f(x) = x^3+x^2+x+7$

b) Prove $f$ has a root between $x=-3$ and $x=-2$

I don't know how to do part b.

Comment: Compute $f(-3)$ and $f(-2)$, then use the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: What's the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: yeah it's x^3+x^2+x+7

Comment: so shall I do f(-3)=(-3)^3+(-3)^2+(-3)+7 then same for -2?

Comment: The IVT says that if $f$ is continuous in the interval $[a,b]$, and $k$ is a number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there is a $c$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(c)=k$. Here we will use $k=0$.

Comment: I don't get it :/ so f(-3)=0? or am I wrong

Comment: Yes, $f(-3)$ is negative and $f(-2)$ is positive, so $f(x)=0$ somewhere in between. The curve cannot get from $(-3, f(-3))$ to $(-2, f(-2))$ without crossing the $x$-axis.

Comment: We have $f(-3)=-27+9-3+7=-14$.

Comment: @user120243 If you make a graph of $f(x)$ with a graphing calculator or some other graphing device, and examine the graph from $x=-3$ to $x=-2$ then you will see that the curve crosses the x-axis. Now, the point for $x=-3$ lies in the third quadrant and the point for $x=-2$ lies in the second quadrant. And so it must cross the x-axis inbetween. That is essentially the intermediate value Theorem Andre is talking about.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the [Intermediate Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).